# How can I Keybind my volume up/down button to click on a Button?

Tags: android

I wanted to develop an app where I can easily send automated SMS through tapping my  Volume key button and I don't know how because I am still new to programming. here's my MainActivity code where I found in my research

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final static int SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 111;
private Button sendMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sendMessage = findViewById(R.id.send_message);
    final EditText phone = findViewById(R.id.phone_no);
    final EditText message = findViewById(R.id.message);
    sendMessage.setEnabled(false);


    if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        sendMessage.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String msg = message.getText().toString();
            String phonenumber = phone.getText().toString();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msg) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(phonenumber)) {

                if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(phone), null, msg, null, null);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter a message and a phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean checkPermission(String permission) {
    int checkPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    return checkPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                sendMessage.setEnabled(true);
            }

            break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the button key event:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
            //add your send text code here
        }
        return true;
    }
```

you can also do it on KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP.  If you don't want to prevent the user from changing the volume while sending the text just `return false` instead of true above.

Comment: I'm still new to programming and may I ask kind sir what would be my send text code in the above?

Comment: @KimLaguican just copy what's inside your  public void onClick(View v), on the sendMessage clickListener

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    wl.acquire();
    // do your things, even when screen is off
}
```

Add this in your on create to make sure key press are listened to even when screen is locked

then

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {
        // ... your code
        return true;
    } else if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)) {
        // ... your code
        return true;
    } else
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Can i ask sir, what would be the code in sending the SMS? I'm not entirely sure of the code of the send SMS that should be inside  // ... your code

Comment: i did not write the code to send sms as u akreadyhave donethat in your code that you posted in question i just have told you the code to listen to the press of volume keys